# SingleEmailMessage limit

Tags: email, limits, singleemailmessage, massemailmessage, whatid

Below links says we can send up to 100 recipients for the To field in Salesforce.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm

Is it still 100 if I use settargetObjectId in singleEmailMessage? In my case SetTargetobjectId is ContactId.

I need to send 300 emails in singleemailmessage and I can't use MassEmailMessage as I cannot set WhatID to customobjectId in Massemailmessage.

> Only contracts, cases, products and opportunities allowed for whatIds
>   in MassEmailMessage

```
List<contact> lstcon=[Select Id,Name,Email,RecordTypeId,RecordType.Name From Contact where RecordType.Name = 'Customer'];
 List<Id> lstids= new List<Id>();
 for(Contact c:lstcon)
 {
  lstids.add(c.id);
 }
 EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'CustomerTemplate' limit 1];

List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for(Integer i=0; i<lstids.size();i++ )
{
If(lstids[i]!=null)
{
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setTargetObjectId(lstids[i]);
mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
mail.setWhatId(customobjectId);
mail.setsaveAsActivity(true);
mailList.add(mail);
}
}
Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is yes. You can use it. When we use `setTargetObjectId` you can send email to 100 recipients.

Also the 100 mail you are mentioning is for toAddress basically it means create a list add 100 email address in that and then you can use that in `SettoAdresses`

from the docs

> You can specify up to **100 recipients for the To field** and up to 25
>   recipients for the CC and BCC fields in each SingleEmailMessage.

Comment: Thank you @Tushar Sharma. Is there a way that I could set whatid to custom objectId in massemailmessage.

Comment: @sfdc I don't think that's possible. You can still post a new question and maybe someone know any hack.